# Generate a cube in Blender Python

Tags: python, blender

I am using Blender 3.0 on Ubuntu 21,10
Why is this code not working? I am trying to randomly generate the x, y and z values of the six vertices of a cube and create it.

This code was inspired by Chris Holt's here https://youtu.be/mljWBuj0Gho

import bpy
import random
name="New Object"
verts=[]
edges=[]
faces=[]

bed = 300 #in mm
print("bed = " + str(bed))

xmin = -bed/2
ymin = -bed/2
zmin = -bed/2
xmax = bed/2
ymax = bed/2
zmax = bed/2

print("xmin" + str(xmin))
print("xmax" + str(xmax))
print("ymin" + str(ymin))
print("ymax" + str(ymax))
print("zmin" + str(zmin))
print("zmax" + str(zmax))

## generate coordinates

## top left back

a1= random.randint(xmin,0)
a2 = random.randint(ymin,0)
a3 = random.randint(0,zmax)

## top right back

b1 = random.randint(xmin,0)
b2 = random.randint(0,ymax)
b3 = random.randint(0,zmax)

## top right front

c1 = random.randint(0,xmax)
c2 = random.randint(0,ymax)
c3 = random.randint(0,zmax)

## top left front

d1 = random.randint(0,xmax)
d2 = random.randint(ymin,0)
d3 = random.randint(0,zmax)

## bottom left back

e1 = random.randint(xmin,0)
e2 = random.randint(ymin,0)
e3 = random.randint(zmin,0)

## bottom right back

f1 = random.randint(xmin,0)
f2 = random.randint(0,ymax)
f3 = random.randint(zmin,0)

## bottom right front

g1 = random.randint(0,xmax)
g2 = random.randint(0,ymax)
g3 = random.randint(zmin,0)
xmax

## bottom left front

h1 = random.randint(0,xmax)
h2 = random.randint(ymin,0)
h3 = random.randint(zmin,0)

print("\n")
print("\n")
print(" a1 =" + str(a1))
print("a2 = " + str(a2))
print("a3 = " + str(a3))

print("\n")
print("b1 = " + str(b1))
print("b2 = " + str(b2))
print("b3 = " + str(b3))

print("\n")
print("c1 = " + str(c1))
print("c2 = " + str(c2))
print("c3 = " + str(c3))

print("\n")
print("d1 = " + str(d1))
print("d2 = " + str(d2))
print("d3 = " + str(d3))

print("\n")
print("e1 = " + str(a1))
print("e2 = " + str(e2))
print("e3 = " + str(e3))

print("\n")
print("f 1= " + str(f1))
print("f 2 = " + str(f2))
print("f3 = " + str(f3))

print("\n")
print("g1 = " + str(g1))
print("g2 = "  + str(g2))
print("g3 = " + str(g3))

print("\n")
print("h1 = " + str(h1))
print("h2 = " + str(h2))
print("h3 = " + str(h3))
print("end")

#8 vertices
verts.append([# index 0
a1, #x
a2, #y
a3 #z
])
verts.append([# index 1
b1, #x
b2, #y
b3 #z
])
verts.append([# index 2
c1, #x
c2, #y
c3 #z
])
verts.append([# index 3
d1, #
d2, #y
d3 #z
])
verts.append([# index 4
e1, #x
e2, #y
e3 #z
])
verts.append([# index 5
f1, #x
f2, #y
f3 #z
])
verts.append([# index 6
g1, #x
g2, #y
g3 #z
])
verts.append([# index 7
h1, #x
h2, #y
h3 #z
])

#12 edges
#top
edges.append([0,1])
edges.append([1,2])
edges.append([2,3])
edges.append([3,0])
#bottom
edges.append([4,5])
edges.append([5,6])
edges.append([6,7])
edges.append([7,4])
#connections
edges.append([0,4])
edges.append([1,5])
edges.append([2,6])
edges.append([3,7])

print(verts[7])
print(edges[0])

#6 facess
#top
faces.append([0,1,2,3])
#bottom
faces.append([4,5,6,7])
#side

## back

faces.append([2,6,10,11])

## front

faces.append([0,1,4,5])

## side right

faces.append([1,2,5,6])

## side left

faces.append([0,3,4,7])

## print"faces[1] = " + str(faces[1])) # doesn't work

print(faces[1])

mesh=bpy.data.meshes.new(name)
print("mesh = " + str(mesh))
obj=bpy.data.objects.new(name,mesh)
print("obj = " + str(obj))
col=bpy.data.collections.get("Collection")
print("col  = " + str(col))
col.objects.link(obj)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active=obj
#mesh.from_pydata(verts,edges,faces)mod_skin = obj.modifiers.new('Skin', 'SKIN')

The error message I am getting is

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/dem.py", line 188, in 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'objects'
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console

Comment: I assume `bpy.data.collections.get("Collections")` returns `None`. Try looking at their docs.

Comment: Yes it does return None. Thanks for looking at this. It was working earlier. I'll look at the docs. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `bpy.data.collections` returns a `bpy.prop_collection` in which you can search by key, using the `get()` method. Here you seem to be searching for a key that doesn't exist. Which is returning `None` and hence your error.

On iterating through the `bpy.data.collections` object using a for loop

```py
for collection in bpy.data.collections:
    print(collection)
```

you can see that the only member is

```
<bpy_struct, Collection("Collection") at 0x7f20e4359848>
```

This is just the default collection that blender has when you open a new project. If you create a new collection named "Collection 2" or something the `for` loop will give you another collection object.

so perhaps what you meant is

```
bpy.data.collections.get("Collection")
```

which will give you the default collection?

Comment: mesh=bpy.data.meshes.new(name)
print("mesh = " + str(mesh))
obj=bpy.data.objects.new(name,mesh)
print("obj = " + str(obj))
col=bpy.data.collections.get("Collection")
print("col  = " + str(col))
col.objects.link(obj)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active=obj
#mesh.from_pydata(verts,edges,faces)mod_skin = obj.modifiers.new('Skin', 'SKIN') Yes changing Collections toCollection worked. But it doesn't seem to be drawing anything in the 3d vieport or it too small.

Comment: There are no errors but its' not creating a cube of the correct size so that I can see it in 3D viewport, Thanks